# Does anyone expect the JVM to ever have reified types?

Tags: jvm, types

I understand the challenge presented by having reified types for the JVM, well, maybe I don't understand it so much as I've heard repeatedly that the JVM simply has no way to support such a concept without breaking backwards compatability.  But that just makes me wonder more, are there plans for reified types in the future or will the JVM simply never have them, like, ever?

Answer (score 2):

All reasons given for type-erasure are ridiculous.  Nobody expects old JVMs to run code compiled against future JDKs.  But you are correct that is the usual explanation.  If you want good generics, I suggest a different language that is actually continuing to evolve.